# Asp.netCore GetWebResourceUrl

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-core

I'm trying to Build my own `ScriptManagerController` which will load JS files from another project.

These files are saved as resource files.

This is the code I used in `Net451`

```
  var url=  Page.ClientScript.GetWebResourceUrl(this.GetType(), "namespace.CustomComboBox.js") + "?JSReloader=" + DateTime.Now.ToFileTime()
var sc= "<script src="+url+"></script>"
```

The problem is that NetAppCore 2.0 dose not have `ClientScriptManager` or `Page` which then I can't use `GetWebResourceUrl`

I could still load the JS file content and then load it throw `HtmlString` which in my case is really bad, my JS file content is really big so I want to avoid it.

Is there a workaround?

### Update

This is what I did, I created a Controller that return a filestream in the other project, and used MapRoute to mapp the namespace of the controller.

I am open to other solutions.

```
  app.MapRoute(
            name: "xxx",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" },
            namespaces: new string[] { "namespace" }
```

Comment: What about just creating a `<script src='@(customSource)' />` tag

Comment: What is `CustomSource`? is it a content if so then it still not good enough.

Comment: It's a string variable

Comment: just like `namespace.CustomComboBox.js`

Comment: No dose not work. you have to understand im loading the whole script from another project.

Answer (score 6):

Follow steps 4, 5, and 6 of this post [including-static-resources-in-razor-class-libraries](https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/330/including-static-resources-in-razor-class-libraries-in-asp-net-core)

4. Create a configuration file.

   ```
   internal class EditorRCLConfigureOptions : IPostConfigureOptions<StaticFileOptions>
   {
       private readonly IHostingEnvironment _environment;

       public EditorRCLConfigureOptions(IHostingEnvironment environment)
       {
           _environment = environment;
       }

       public void PostConfigure(string name, StaticFileOptions options)
       {

           // Basic initialization in case the options weren't initialized by any other component
           options.ContentTypeProvider = options.ContentTypeProvider ?? new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();

           if (options.FileProvider == null && _environment.WebRootFileProvider == null)
           {
               throw new InvalidOperationException("Missing FileProvider.");
           }

           options.FileProvider = options.FileProvider ?? _environment.WebRootFileProvider;


           // Add our provider
           var filesProvider = new ManifestEmbeddedFileProvider(GetType().Assembly, "resources");
           options.FileProvider = new CompositeFileProvider(options.FileProvider, filesProvider);
       }
   }
   ```
5. (Optional) Create an extension class (you could also skip and use the `services.ConfigureOptions` line directly in the `Startup` class.

   ```
    public static class EditorRCLServiceCollectionExtensions
   {
       public static void AddEditor(this IServiceCollection services)
       {
           services.ConfigureOptions(typeof(EditorRCLConfigureOptions));
       }
   }
   ```
6. Add the new service to the startup class's `ConfigureServices` method:

   ```
   services.AddEditor();
   ```

Now you can use a file path just like a `Content` file, but for Embedded Resources!

`<script src='@(pathToEmbeddedResource)' />`

Comment: Hi, I dont have reference to `HostingEnvironment` in my NetAppCore 2.0. its not an MVC Project. An MVC project will have a reference to this project. is there a repleacement ?

Comment: Ok i hade to add nuget packages to get those, but what are ManifestEmbeddedFileProvider and CompositeFileProvider

Comment: Sorry, just back up to step 3 on the link I used. Install the nuget packages listed there, should include those classes

Comment: Well there is to many references, I would have too add this project to nuget, and would like to avoid to many references. Is there any other way of doing it.